# Give points to user just on first signup with Facebook in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, model-view-controller, devise, omniauth

I use Facebook-omniauth gem with devise to register users
Here is what i have in my callback

```
class CallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook
    @user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
  end
end
```

I want to add to each new user,7000 points,for the first time they register.
In the above code I tried to add `resource.update(points: 7000)` and it does work,when the user sign up,he gets 7000 points,the problem is that when i sign out,and sign in again the number is again 7000 though it should be less as the user used some of that points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a column in the `users` table called `"sign_in_count"`, when the user signs up for the first time it should be 0, check if it's zero then add 7000, if not don't add anything

Something like this :

```
resource.update(points: 7000) if resource.sign_in_count == 0
```

Comment: what would you write into the migration file?

Comment: @MikeMcCallen You don't need any migrations, you already have that column if you are using devise.

Comment: I already got into this trap in the past,by editing the schema.rb directly,it ended really bad,as it is not recommended to change it manually.Will it be safe? what are your thoughts? i did find the "sign_in_count,with 0 default...

Comment: your second edit gives a undefined local variable or method `sign_in_count'

Comment: @MikeMcCallen You might need to do if resource.sign_in_count == 1, because I think that field is incremented by 1 once your sign_up